# Digit Freqency Problem in C, Not getting correct frequency for large input

Tags: c, string, while-loop

The problem is to get the frequency of digits in given input string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    char s[1000];
    scanf("%s", s);
    int index = 0;
    int len=strlen(s);
    int count[10] = {0};
    
    while(index!=len){
        //printf("%c",s[index]);
        count[s[index++] - 48]++;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       printf("%d ", count[i]);
    
    return 0;
 
}
```

when given small string input it is working but for the following input

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

I am getting output as
32 32 39 37 34 34 40 37 46 30

but actual output is
32 33 40 40 35 35 39 36 48 29

Where am i Going wrong

Comment: You aren't checking if a value is a digit or not so this program with that input accesses outside the bounds of the count array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s[index++] - 48` - if `s[index++]` is 'a', the result is 97 - 48, is 49. `count[49]` is out of the array bounds access, leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68917926/4989451) there is Undefined Behavior in the program due to buffer overflow.

I suggest to filter out non-digits before updating `count` using `isdigit()` function.

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

char c = s[index++];
if (isdigit(c))
   count[c - '0']++;
```